# Automatic refresh webapp page after database update

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, refresh

I am breaking my head for a while now with this problem.
I am building a web app in php and jQuery Mobile that will be used for the judging of snowboard contests.

the flow of the app:

1. a Headjudge give a score (range) to a rider after his jump
2. an X-amount of judges receive the score on their tablet after the headjudge submitted the range.
3. The judges give separately an updated score and submit it to db
4. The headjudge can approve the score and store it in db or he can disapprove the score and send it back to the judge from which the score is.
5. After headjudge approved all scores the next rider can go and all the steps start over

My problem is I can't find a way to refresh the pages of the judges after headjudge submits something. Same goes for the headjudge because he also has to receive the scores of the judges.

I hope this is enough information.

thanks in advance

yannick

Comment: Look into periodic polling using AJAX, or a long-lived AJAX call. If hardware is standardized perhaps look into web sockets.

Comment: Unfortunately you've hit one of the weak points of Web apps in general and Apache/PHP in particular. Try reading up on COMET; I've not used it but it's built for things like this. If I were starting from scratch I'd consider using a framework with sockets. Java springs to mind but there are many.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Yannick You can use the flush command to update the page or ob_end_flush(); that will let you refresh the page.